# Splunk will soon be sponsoring DevOps Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship

We're excited to announce that [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/) will be sponsoring DevOps Stack Exchange beginning **July 7th through December 31**. We wanted to give you a heads-up and walk you through what it will look like.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown on the right side of the header at the top of the site in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

[image: Splunk Banner Mockup]

### What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside
> our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the
> questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections
> as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a
> garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits
> still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has
> always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all
> Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for
> sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

### What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

Also, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making DevOps Stack Exchange successful.